# Trigger On Very Short Pulse - VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I'm using a CMOD A7 (Artix 7) and I need to trigger a process based on a pulse of around 10ns duration (blue line):

[image: Tektronix]

Normally I'd do triggering like this by having a process constantly compare the current value of the input line with the last value using a temporary register to hold the last value. However, I believe the oscillator on this board has a period of around 83ns which is far too slow for this approach.

If I was using pure digital electronics, this would be easy, connect a flipflop to the trigger, poll the output of that flipflop (which would change and latch with the input) and then reset it once I've read it and started my actions. So I would imagine there's a way to do this in VHDL but I'm led to believe using `if rising_edge()` on non-clock signals is a no-go.

Where do I start with this?

Comment: *So I would imagine there's a way to do this in VHDL but I'm led to believe using `if rising_edge()` on non-clock signals is a no-go*. Any such restriction would be target technology based and even that can be overcome (e.g. a MS flip flop out of gates). *Where do I start with this?* What have you tried? This doesn't appear [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: In the limited sense that this a VHDL question, and not an electronics question, you can use `rising_edge` on any signal you want. It's just a function name. VHDL has no knowledge or understanding of 'clocks'. Your actual problem is what, in your target technology, can be connected to a clock pin of a sequential element, and whether the STA can cope.

Comment: I would not let a logic synthesiser anywhere near this. My background is IC design, not FPGA, and on an IC I'd design this by hand, at gate-level. I'd chose carefully which cells from the library I wanted, instantiate them myself (in VHDL/Verilog) and pay close attention to how they were laid out. (Basically, I'd be asking the layout engineer to hand-place these cells.) I would advise doing whatever is possible in an FPGA flow that is as close as possible to what I'd do in an IC flow. Basically, you need to "use digital electronics", but on your FPGA.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution here is twofold:

Firstly, I can derive a 100MHz clock using the onboard MCCM and Vivado's `ClockWiz` IP.

I can also use the `FDCE` component provided by Vivado to utilise one of the onboard flipflops to extend the pulses and reset it after passing it through a few flipflops for synchronisation.

I've not tested this yet but I believe it should work:

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
library unisim;
use unisim.vcomponents.all;

entity input_syncroniser is
    generic
    (
        in_pipe_len: in positive := 5
    );
    
    port
     (
        clk : in STD_LOGIC;
        rst : in STD_LOGIC;
        din : in STD_LOGIC;
        
        dfo : out STD_LOGIC
      );
end input_syncroniser;

architecture behavioural of input_syncroniser is

    signal delayed_pulse:   std_logic := '0';
    signal in_pipe:         std_logic_vector(in_pipe_len - 1 downto 0) := (others => '0'); 
    signal pipe_head:       std_logic := '0';
    
begin

    FDCE_inst : FDCE
    generic map 
    (
        INIT => '0'
    ) 
        port map 
    (
        Q => delayed_pulse,
        C => din,
        CE => '1',
        CLR => pipe_head, 
        D => '1'
    );


    input_synchroniser: process(clk)
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clk)) then
            in_pipe <= in_pipe(in_pipe'high downto in_pipe'low) & delayed_pulse;
        end if;
    end process;

    pipe_head <= in_pipe(in_pipe'high);
    dfo <= pipe_head;


end behavioural;
```